# What further steps can I take to distinguish a question incorrectly closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

The perfect question for my problem is erroneously closed as a duplicate. The one answer doesn't work; in fact, it's an answer to the (allegedly) duplicated question. Maybe that (and the fact that the answer was, at one point, accepted) is part of the problem.

[Sublime Text 2: Select all instances of variable and then edit variable name [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844657/sublime-text-2-select-all-instances-of-variable-and-then-edit-variable-name)

I've done [all the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) [right things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) to get it reopened:

1. I commented on the question itself
2. I commented on the unsatisfactory answer
3. I carefully examined the alleged duplicate to make sure it was different
4. I edited the question to highlight the differences
5. I flagged it for moderator attention ... twice, or tried to, anyway - see below
6. I'm asking about it on Meta

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEaiD.png]

Comment: Was the flag declined or is it still pending?

Comment: Pending, I guess... Do I get a notification if it's declined?

Comment: @Nolan Check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/483520

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's what I assumed at first as well, but it seems that it still matches the original question asked, and the OP did not accept the existing answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell carefully read the original, unedited question. You'll see Oskar uses the words "variable" and "stroke", not "string" and "highlight".

Comment: @FDinoff Pending - "1 waiting for review" (since August 19th)

Comment: Then just wait a moderator hasn't see the flag yet.

Comment: It got unaccepted about three days ago, so I was definitely seeing things just now.

Comment: I actually said it was accepted in my question above; I'll make the edit.

Comment: @Nolan: tip: next time comment before you edit. The comments are visible in the reopen review queue, more noticeable than the edit summary. (Well, unless there's 50 comments already...)

Comment: Is the consensus that I should just wait for a moderator?

Comment: @yes, really. If you think a question shouldn't be a closed as a dupe because it's not a dupe due to a subtle distinction you can see but others can't, bring the distinction to the fore so everyone can see it. I know it's ironic that your "this isn't a dupe" is itself a dupe, but so be it.

Comment: Seems like it got reopened. Congrats. I wish everyone were like you in opening straightforward and clear reopening process.

Comment: @KateGregory So I *should* post to meta to get the question reopened, but I should expect my meta question to get closed?

Comment: Update: My hard work pays off - question answered. Huzzah!

Comment: @Nolan first, meta question being closed doesn't stop mission from being accomplished. Second, "please open this question" isn't a dupe, but "what can I do about wrongly-closed dupes" is.

Comment: @KateGregory That wouldn't be closed as a non-question?

Comment: Hardly any of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question are closed for being non questions

Comment: This was intended to be a specific-question question (the title was edited), but okay, next time I'll say: "Could you please reopen this question?".

Comment: My sympathies.  I had a question unjustly closed as a duplicate also.  Felt bullied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number six in your list is pretty much the end of the line. Meta is the final appeals court for stuff like this. Action tends to be taken pretty quickly one way or the other once a post is highlighted here -- although it may not always be the action you're desiring or requesting.

You have indeed done all the right things; all you can do now is wait for other members to vote.

Two notes, though, if I may -- you can't re-flag because your original flag has not been processed yet. You should, ideally, wait until that happens before raising the issue here.

Second, the edits you performed on the question invalidated the accepted (at the time) answer by listing as "not working" exactly the things that the OP indicated *had* worked. This is also not ideal. It seems that the OP agreed with you and un-accepted the answer, so it's water under the bridge, but if you run into this again, I'd say you should make your own post that includes the distinguishing information.

Thanks for putting all this work into the question!

Comment: I was tempted to make a new question when the original answerer snarkily suggested I do so ("@Nolan - feel free to ask a question and see if anyone has any suggestions." - "ask a question" was linked), but as the existing question really was  *exactly* the one I had, and the answer didn't work, I decided to edit it to clarify. To be clear, I didn't change the intent of the question; I think the OP accepted the answer because it provided workarounds (e.g., `⌘-U` soft-undo).

Comment: And for the record, I was poking fun at myself (and my zealotry) with the re-flag screenshot :)

Comment: Perhaps "What doesn't work:" was a little aggressive and might cause people to not try some of the useful shortcuts in the original answer ... I'll change it to "Things I've tried:"

Comment: I'm not sure that was snark -- it _can_ be okay to post a new question even if it's very similar, as long as you can distinguish it from the original. It could be that the OP was using the wrong terminology, for example -- even though e _said_ "variable", maybe e was actually only looking for "string", and was satisfied with the answer given.

Comment: I don't really think you did anything wrong here, @Nolan, and I respect the effort you've put into this situation. My notes were just meant to be suggestive for the future. Maybe they were also a little aggressive...

Comment: Nope, the notes are helpful. It's hard to say for sure that the OP meant what I meant (though I do think he did), and it seems like a judgment call as to whether to open a new question or edit the existing one in that case. Anyway, thanks for the thanks!